# NLog Concurrent Requests into different files

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, concurrency, asp.net-web-api2, nlog

As the title suggests, I am trying to log separate requests to my .NET Web API controllers to separate files.

With the introduction of `{var}`, here is what I am trying inside my c# code.

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("test");
[HttpPost, Route("xyz")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(Obj value)
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    LogManager.Configuration.Variables["test"] = guid.ToString();
    logger.Info(value);
    //do my execution here.
}
```

My Nlog.Config looks like this:

```xml
<variable name="test" value=""/>
<targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="File" 
    name="concurrents" 
    fileName="${basedir}/nlogs/${logger}/${var:test}.log" 
    layout="${uppercase:${level}} |  ${callsite} | ${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss.fff} | &quot;${message}&quot;" 
    createDirs="true" />
    </target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="test" minlevel="Info" writeTo="concurrents"></logger>
</rules>
```

As you all might already know,

When concurrent requests come in, I am trying to log each and every requests by creating a creating a new Guid and assinging it to the `{var}` and creating the file in the name of the var.

The logs somehow gets mixed up and one half of the request is in one file and the other half in another.

To be quite honest, I think I am missing some fundamental thing that I should know about but not sure where.

It would be great if someone could point to the right direction and help me understand how can I go about logging current request in different files.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are at global level and that won't work with a multi-threaded environment (http request)

A good solution is to set the guid on HttpContext level:

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["myvariable"] = guid.ToString();
```

and use

```
${aspnet-item:variable=myvariable}
```

You need [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/) package for ASP.NET Core - for ASP.NET non-core you need  [NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try your suggestion and would get back to you. As you pointed out "Variables are at global level and that won't work with a multi-threaded environment". I am now sure I do not know the fundamentals of using var. Could you point out to me some article explaining the same. Would be really helpful. Cheers.

Comment: @Sandeep Maybe these can help: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDLC-Layout-Renderer and https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables

Comment: You could see the variable as scoped globally, like a `static` .NET field

Comment: Hey @Julian. Sorry for the delay in response. Yep, followed your suggestion and got it working. Cheers for your time.